# Hibenate validation on items in list not coimpile nor workink

Tags: kotlin, hibernate-validator

I am migrating Java spring application to Kotlin spring application.

I have the following dto kotlin class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
data class filter(
    @Schema(
        title = "Collection of ids",
        example = "[\"2f21b7ed-11ec-43b7-ba89-2d014d61a168\", \"367693c6-5aef-40f0-9f91-fea8ad4e76ca\"]"
    )
    @field:NotNull
    @field:Size(min = 1, max = 20)
    val ids: Set<@UUID String>? = null,

    @Schema(title = "Collection of names", example = "[\"Group-A\", \"Group-B\"]")
    val names: @Size(min = 1, max = 20) MutableSet<String>? = null
) {
}
```

When using the filter oject in a controller, the `field:NotNull`
is being validated,and when I do not provide the field ids, the controller is not called by spring and 400 is returned.

The UUID annotation in the set property is not working, I assumed it because I am missing the part of the `@field:` but using it with in the generic type of the collection causes compilation error.
So the question is how to use UUID validation annotation on a generic type in a list in kotlin?

Comment: The problem is that validation annotations can be used near variable, but `String` here is a type parameter of a generic class. You need a custom annotation above the `ids` variable

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator